# Condition for the generators through any one of the ends of an equi-conjugate diameter of the principal elliptic section of the hyperboloid

Tags: 3d

> **Question**: Show that the generators through any one of  the ends of an equi-conjugate diameter of the principal elliptic section of the hyperboloid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1$ are inclined to each other at an angle of $60 ^\circ$ if $a^2+b^2=6c^2$.

**Solution**: I took the point on the diameter as $(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta,0)$ . So the two generators through this point are 
$$\begin{align} 
\frac{x-a\cos\theta}{a\sin\theta}=\frac{y-b\sin\theta}{-b\cos\theta}=\frac{z}{\pm c} 
\end{align}$$

So the direction ratios of two generators are $(a\sin\theta,-b\cos\theta,c)$ and $(a\sin\theta, -b\cos\theta,-c)$ respectively.

$$\begin{align} 
\cos\theta &=\frac{l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2}{\sqrt{{l_1}^2+{m_1}^2+{n_1}^2}\sqrt{{l_2}^2+{m_2}^2+{n_3}^2}} \\
\implies \cos\theta &=\frac{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta-c^2}{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta+c^2}
\end{align}$$

Putting $\theta = 60^\circ$ and solving I got $3a^2+b^2 = 12c^2$

I am wondering whether the question is wrong or I missed anything or my approach itself is wrong. Appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha = 60^\circ$ is the angle between two generators not the parameter of end points of conjugal diameters.

$$\begin{align} 
\cos\alpha &=\frac{l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2}{\sqrt{{l_1}^2+{m_1}^2+{n_1}^2}\sqrt{{l_2}^2+{m_2}^2+{n_3}^2}} \\
\implies \cos\alpha &=\frac{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta-c^2}{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta+c^2}
\end{align}$$

Putting $\alpha = 60^\circ$ and $\theta = 45^\circ (\because $ equi-conjugal diameters means equal length of conjugal diameters i.e. $\sqrt {a^2cos^2\theta+b^2sin^2\theta} = \sqrt {a^2sin^2\theta+b^2cos^2\theta}$ which is possible for $\theta = 45^\circ$)

Putting values of $\theta$ and $\alpha$ you get the answer $a^2+b^2 = 6c^2$